# How to convert my equation (Exponential) to cot form?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, exponential-function, exponentiation, trigonometric-series

I have the below equation:

$$
F(t)=(k_1 e^{at} + (k_{Re}-ik_{Im})(\lambda+i\omega)e^{(\lambda+i\omega)t}+(k_{Re}+ik_{Im})(\lambda-i\omega)e^{(\lambda-i\omega)t})/((r_1k_1 e^{at} + r_2(k_{Re}-ik_{Im})(\lambda+i\omega)e^{(\lambda+i\omega)t}+r_3(k_{Re}+ik_{Im})(\lambda-i\omega)e^{(\lambda-i\omega)t})) 
$$

where $r_1, r_2$ and $r_3$ also have real and Imaginary parts. Plotting the equation, it has below form:

$$
F(t) = C_1 - C_2 cot( \omega t )
$$

My question is: Is it possible to achieve to $cot( \omega t)$ form analytically? and how!

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: `Plotting the equation` But $F(t)$ is not even real in general, unless there are additional untold assumptions on those constants.

Comment: If you let $k_{Re}+ik_{Im} = k$ and

$\lambda+i\omega = \eta$, then you get
$F(t)=
\dfrac{k_1 e^{at} + \overline k \overline \eta e^{\eta t}+k \overline \eta e^{\overline \eta t}}
{r_1k_1 e^{at} + r_2\overline k \eta e^{\eta t}+r_3 k \overline \eta e^{\overline \eta t}}$. I don't think this simplifies any more as it is.